# How to add a string to a vector of strings in an unordered map in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, unordered-map

Trying to create an unordered map of strings where each string is coupled with a pointer to a vector of strings.
But I cannot add a string to the vector().
Getting the error:
invalid use of ‘class std::vector >’

Does this code do that in a right way?

```
#include  < unordered_map>  
#include  < string>

#include  < vector>          
using namespace std;


int main()

{

    unordered_map<string, vector<string*> > hashtable;

    hashtable.insert(make_pair( "car1", vector<string*>()));

    hashtable.insert(make_pair( "car2", vector<string*>()));

    hashtable["car1"].vector<string*>()->insert("change_oil");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are the `\\`` in front of your `#include`s intentional?

Comment: Why a container of pointers to `string`? What is `hashtable["car1"].vector<string*>()` supposed to do? So many questions...

Comment: Why the made-up syntax? `hashtable["car1"].vector<string*>()->insert("change_oil")` makes no sense. Don't guess; read manuals and follow the rules.

Comment: you don't  have a pointer to a vector, you have a vector of pointers (and pointers to `string` are very odd).

Answer (score 1):

`hashtable["car1"]` denotes the `vector`, so you just have to add something to it, like `hashtable["car1"].push_back(new string("change_oil"))`.

You need to use a pointer to `string`, this is why I used `new`. A string litteral is (can be convert as) a `string` not a `string *`.

If you want to use `insert` you must use another argument to provide the position of the insertion.

May I suggest you not to use `vector<string *>` but `vector<string>`. In your case, it will be much more harder to manage correctly your (de)allocations

Answer (score 1):

> How to add a string to a vector of strings

No, your map doesn't hold a vector of strings. It holds a vector of pointers to strings.

> where each string is coupled with a pointer to a vector of strings

No, it is coupled with a vector. Not a pointer to one.

> Does this code do that in a right way?

No, that code does not even compile.

```
hashtable["car1"].vector<string*>()
```

There is no syntax like this in c++.

```
->insert("change_oil")
```

Your vector contains pointers to `std::string` objects. You cannot initialize such pointer with a string literal. Also, `vector::insert` expects an iterator to the position you want to insert to which you failed to provide.

Now for the question...

> How to add a string to a vector of strings in an unordered map

It's quite simple. First define an unordered map of strings to vectors of strings.

```
unordered_map<string, vector<string> > hashtable;
```

The `operator[]` of the map will return a reference to the vector. If the element does not exist, it will be added, so your insert is redundant (but you may keep it if it is clearer to you). Call `push_back` on the returned reference to add a string to the vector.

```
hashtable["car1"].push_back("change_oil");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown out because in your vector, the item is `string *`, while what you insert at line :

`hashtable["car1"].vector<string*>()->insert("change_oil");`

is `char *` ("change_oil").

In your case, I think it's better use `vector<string>` while not `vector<string *>`.